# Python program to calculate mean of score in file

Tags: python-3.x

I wrote a program to calculate average of score of each person from csv file:

```
import csv
# For the average
from statistics import mean 
from collections import OrderedDict

def calculate_averages(input_file_name, output_file_name):
    with open(input_file_name, newline='') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            with open(output_file_name, mode='w') as w:
                w = csv.writer(output_file_name, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
                li = list()
                li[0] = row[0]
                li[1] = mean(row[1:])
                w.writerow(li)

calculate_averages('in.csv','out.csv')
```

but it's now working
help me please!

and my csv file is like:

```
mandana,5,7,3,15
hamid,3,9,4,20,9,1,8,16,0,5,2,4,7,2,1
sina,19,10,19,6,8,14,3
sara,0,5,20,14
soheila,13,2,5,1,3,10,12,4,13,17,7,7
ali,1,9
sarvin,0,16,16,13,19,2,17,8
```

TypeError: argument 1 must have a "write" method

Comment: Please be a liiittle more specific about what's not working as expected. Don't make your would-be volunteers scrounge for meaning in your post.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? What happens when you run it? What did you expect it to do instead?

Comment: Don't say "it doesn't work".  Explain the way in which it doesn't work.  Do you get no output?  Incorrect output?  If it's incorrect, what makes it incorrect, and what would the correct output be?  Don't expect that the reader knows what "working" means for you.  Where possible, provide a paste of any error output, as the specific error message is often helpful to those trying to diagnore your problem.  Supplying specific versions and library names is often also helpful, at least for the components that directly touch your problem.

Comment: question is edited!

Comment: What line number does Python tell you the error appears on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work. Note the values are read as strings, so you need convert them first to values before you take the mean, as done in `vals = [float(val) for val in row[1:]]`

```
import csv
from statistics import mean

def calculate_averages(input_file_name, output_file_name):

    with open(input_file_name, mode='rt', newline='') as csv_in:
        csv_content = csv.reader(csv_in)
        with open(output_file_name, mode='wt', newline='') as csv_out:
            csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_out, delimiter=',')
            for row in csv_content:
                vals = [float(val) for val in row[1:]]
                csv_writer.writerow([row[0], mean(vals)])    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    calculate_averages('in.csv','out.csv')
```

Answer (score 1):

the lines:

```
with open(output_file_name, mode='w') as w:
                w = csv.writer(output_file_name, delimiter= ...
```

you can see you're defining `w` twice. once as the file descriptor and then as the csv writer.

you need to pass `w` (the descriptor) as the first argument to `csv.writer()`. this is why i presume it's giving you an error. you're passing `str` as the first arg which doesn't have a `.write()`.